# How to predict the given value is anomaly or not with trained pyod.LOCI and Machine learning models?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, usage-statistics

I used the pyod.loci model to detect outliers. Trained the model with 100 records data.
I see most of the outliers detector models find the outliers with in the data only.   I want to use the same trained model to predict the unseen data point whether it is anomaly or not?.
 Can some one help me with an idea or solution? Model should work for individual or multiple column data as well.

Comment: What did you try so far? What exactly is working/not working? What's your input, what's your expected output?

Comment: I trained pyod.loci() with 1d, 100 points. Tried to predict by loci.predict() for one new point. It always returning 0 flag even its an outlier. But returning correct if I try to predict with at least 20 points. I can't understand it.